# Incomplete file list when browsing file system of Nexus 5 in Windows 7 / 10

Tags: file-system, windows, file-management, 6.0-marshmallow

I connected my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0) to my Windows PC via USB (tried both MTP and PTP mode) and noticed that the file list in Explorer was incomplete. I compared the file list in ES on my Android device to the file list that Windows Explorer shows and discovered that the majority of files and folders was missing in the Windows file list. I tried both Windows 7 and 10 - same effect. 
Did anybody else have this issue?

Comment: Can you list  the files that were available under ES File Explorer but not in Windows Explorer? [Use a paste service](https://gist.github.com/) to mention them here.

Comment: Let's take this example. This is the full file list I obtained via ES Remote Manager: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f2516cbd3f05d372950
Only the first two (sorted by name) are displayed in Windows:
voice-2014-08-08-13-02.mp3 and 
voice-2014-08-08-13-16.mp3

Comment: I had this issue a while back, and to be honest I never found out why it happened. Sometimes refreshing explorer helped, sometimes not. It was certainly strange.